# Concatenating 2-dimensional ragged arrays (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to concatenate two two-dimensional arrays of different sizes. I have no idea why my method doesn't work. Java tells me, when I mouse over the "return xx": "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int[][] to int[]". When I mouse over "concatenateArr2d..." I get: "Illegal modifier for parameter concatenateArr2d: only final is permitted".

I don't understand why I am getting this error.

```
    public static int[][] concatenateArr2d(int[][] t, int[][] s)
{
    int[][] xx = new int[t.length + s.length][];
    for(i = 0; i < xx.length; i++)
    {
        xx[i] = new int[t[i].length + s[i].length];
    }
    return xx;
}
```

I still have to do the code to fill the entries but that should not be a problem.

Any help please? Thank you.

Comment: If only allowed modifier is `final`, that suggests to me that you're inside a method when you declare this method.  Check the curly-braces before this code.

Comment: Oh haha, thank you! Silly me...pardon my greenness.

Comment: While that may have solved the issue at hand, you are going to run into some more problems when you actually attempt to run this. `xx[i] = new int[t[i].length + s[i].length];` is going to always result in an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that the code before the bit you pasted does not have aligned braces.  You're probably inside a method when you try to declare this method.

Comment: This answers the OP's question.  It does not fix the IndexOutOfBoundsException bug, but the OP didn't ask about that.

Comment: No worries, I wasn't complaining about the downvote.  Downvotes happen, often with good reason.  I was just explaining what I was answering, in case anyone later gets confused.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class HelloWorld{

public static int[][] concatenateArr2d(int[][] t, int[][] s)
{

int jLength=0;
// The below line of code is to determine second dimension size of new array
jLength=Math.max(s[0].length, t[0].length);


int sIterate=0;
//new array created using size of first+second array for First dimension and maximum size for second dimension
int[][] xx = new int[t.length + s.length][jLength];

//first array copy
for(int i = 0; i < t.length; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < t[0].length; j++)
    {
    xx[i][j] =t[i][j];
    }
}
//second array copy
for(int i = t.length; i < xx.length; i++)
{

    for(int j = 0; j < s[0].length; j++)
    {
    xx[i][j] =s[sIterate][j];
    }
    sIterate++;
}
return xx;
}
public static void main(String []args){
     int a[][]={{1,2},{2,3},{1,1}};
     int b[][]={{1,2,3},{2,3,4}};
     int c[][]=HelloWorld.concatenateArr2d(a,b);
     //Output iteration
     for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < c[0].length; j++)
    {
    System.out.print(c[i][j]);
    }
     System.out.println();
}
 }
}



note : The blanks filled by 'primitive type default value' like, for int its 0.

Output :
120
230
110
123
234
```

Comment: @PaulHicks It's doing the concatenation. Though it could be a little cleaner... It also does not allow for variable sized arrays in the resulting 2D array.

Comment: @Arunkumar Cool. Can you add an explanation outside of the code? Explain how it works, what the important line is, stuff like that? Turn it from a programme to an answer

Comment: @PaulHicks It will take variable sized array and can result variable sized array.